# "getCalendarById" is not defined

Tags: google-apps-script

What is wrong with my Code.gs that gives me "getCalendarById" is not defined? Also If I add CalendarApp. in front of the getCalendarById method the whole thing breaks and the URL returns nothing but a drive error.

Solution:
I do have to add CalendarApp in front of getCalendarById I read the doc wrong ([doc link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization)). In that doc under the section 'Granting Access Rights' I read  -

Scripts do not request authorization if they...or if you access the script as a web app that runs under the script owner's user identity.

I was running the script under my own identity but failed to realize that the quote above meant it will not go out and get authorization, not that **it still requires you to get it yourself** . Many thanks to  Serge insas for his great help, sticking with me and understanding.

Code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index.html').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}

function listEvents(dateSelected) {
  var calendar = getCalendarById('en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com').getEventsForDay(new Date(dateSelected)); // if I put calendarapp. the whole thing returns an error from the URL

  Logger.log('Number of events: ' + calendar.length);
}
```

html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="container" >
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <p>Please select a date below.</p>
      <p>Click Here: <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" /><p> 
    </div>
</div>
<div id='test'></div>

<script>
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
$("#datepicker").on("change", function () {
var dateSelected = $(this).val()
$("#test").text(dateSelected);
google.script.run.listEvents(dateSelected);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getCalendarById()` is a method of the `calendarApp` service, the correct syntax is as follows :

```
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("xxxxxxxx");
```

See [doc here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getCalendarById%28String%29)

Comment: When I add the CalendarApp portion the web app wont render and just gives me a goolge drive error.

Comment: Have you authorized your script?

Comment: authorized as in hit the deploy as webapp, run as myself, and accessible to anyone?

Comment: sorry, was away... no, run doGet from script editor to get the authorization on Calendar service (and more if any)

Comment: No it didnt work. Also the docs say that if its specifically a webapp running at as yourself for your own calendars. Sorry for the delay in response. Try to learn app script is depressing me badly. Thanks for all your help in this and the other stackexchange questions.

Comment: Running as yourself doesn't mean run without authorization...could you update your question with your full code please?

Comment: please have a look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570143/unable-to-deploy-google-apps-script-as-a-web-app it might explain your issue.

Comment: I've updated my code with the solution and thank you again for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped and thx for mentioning in your edit :)