# Unable to deploy Google Apps Script as a Web App

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-docs

I'm not able to deploy Google Apps Script as a web app since yesterday. I am getting the following error[image: Google Drive Encountered an error] (please see the screenshot)

I've tried to use different computers, different google accounts and different networks, to no avail.

Would request for prompt support. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just tested and working fine... EXCEPT that when using a class that need authorization I don't get an authorization request but the error message you show instead. I ran doGet from the editor to get the authorization then it worked as expected. Could you give it a try and update accordingly ? thx

Comment: Yes it working from the editor itself. However, when we deploy (even after giving authorization), its throwing the error, I wrote above. Somebody, please help.

Comment: This has affected majority of my projects. Requesting for prompt support.

Comment: Double checked this: We are getting a 500 Internal Server Error for our old Apps Script Projects as well. Is someone else also getting this same issue?

@Google: Please resolve this soon. Seriously affected.

Comment: I can't comment yet so I wanted to provide this link to an issue I opened about this.
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3637&thanks=3637&ts=1391617587

Comment: Could you provide with a simple snippet of code with which you can reproduce this? Also, could you tell us if you are deploying these apps to run as the end user or the developer? After a couple of tries we have been unable to reproduce this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi all the quick fix is as follow:

add these lines of code at the end of you doPost() method

> var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
>     return app;

This should fix the problem and now it's returning 200 (ok).